# Alethzero QOpenGLWidget issue

Tags: cpp-ethereum, bug, alethzero

I have downloaded and built the latest alethzero client. I have Qt5.5 installed. Running on Ubuntu 14.04

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
QObject::connect: No such signal dev::aleth::Aleth::knownAddressesChanged(AccountNamer*)
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'Main')
QObject::connect: No such signal dev::aleth::Aleth::addressNamesChanged(AccountNamer*)
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'Main')
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current
Remote debugging server started successfully. Try pointing a Chromium-based browser to http://127.0.0.1:14633
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
```

Comment: Where did you download it? Why dont you install it from the repositories?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, unless you have a specific need to build from source yourself, I would agree that you are better off just using the PPA.

http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/installing-binaries/linux-ubuntu-ppa.html

Trusty is a bit of a pig for us to build against, because many packages are so old there now, so using OUR binaries will give you a much easier ride.

If you are determined to build from source then all power to you.   In that case, please log an issues with all the details against http://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella.